# Deduplicate array of similar javascript objects

Tags: javascript

Given an array of unknown length of objects that looks like:

```
[{id: '10001-10002', source: 10001, target: 10002}, {id: '10002-10001', source: 10002, target: 10001}]
```

How can I deduplicate the opposites?

Desired result for above:

```
[{id: '10001-10002', source: 10001, target: 10002}]
```

Comment: is it just the id that you want to deduplicate? or the whole object?

Comment: what have you tried? SO is not a code writing service

Comment: I have tried nesting for loops and combining filter and map.

Comment: Either deduplication of the ID or whole object can get me where I need to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you EKD! You gave me an idea!!! I modified your code and the objet slightly to achieve the deduplication of opposites. Added an "reverse" id string as rId to the object and compared that to the item id.

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: '10001-10002', source: 10001, target: 10002, rId: '10002-10001'},
  {id: '10002-10001', source: 10002, target: 10001, rId: '10001-10002'},
];

const result = myArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const alreadyExist = acc.some(item => item.id === cur.rId);
  if (alreadyExist) return acc;
  return [...acc, cur];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "filter" by id, I think this will fits to you.

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: '10001-10002', source: 10001, target: 10002},
  {id: '10002-10001', source: 10002, target: 10001},
  {id: '10001-10002', source: 10001, target: 10002}
];

const result = myArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const alreadyExist = acc.some(item => item.id === cur.id);
  if (alreadyExist) return acc;
  return [...acc, cur];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I modified your answer slightly to get my desired result. Want to give as much credit to you as I can. Do you want to modify your answer to my solution so I can give you the check?

Comment: No way. I helped you, but you reached there. I think we work as a team, so the award is our! Great job.